# Update MYSQL table by comparing columns

Tags: mysql

please I need help.
If I have a MYSQL table that looks like the one in the image below, for instance:

```
Full Name     Customer _ Type Referrer 
Wayne Brown   Standard        Neil White 
Neil White    Standard        Wayne Brown 
Gordon Smith  Standard        Neil White 
Rukky Dick    Standard        Neil White 
Dorothy Ann   Standard        Tracy Cool 
Tracy Cool    Standard        Neil White 
Anthony Josh  Standard        Neil White
```

How do I write an UPDATE statement to change someone like Neil White's customer type to "Premium" because he has referred 5 or more people?

I have tried this code but it's not giving me the result.

```
Update customers set customer_type = “Premium” where full_name = (select referrer from customers having count(referrer) >= 5)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post code here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: You'd use `COUNT()` (possibly with HAVING) or `num_rows()` and `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
UPDATE `your_table` as t1 
    INNER JOIN (select count(*) as `total` 
            from `your_table` as t2 
            where t2.`full_name_customer`= t1.`full_name_customer`
            group by t2.`referrer`
     ) as t3
 SET`full_name_customer`='Premium' 
 WHERE t3.total >= 5
```